# Running multiple queries in prepared statement in batch

Tags: java, sql, db2, prepared-statement

I have a scenario where i want to insert record if it doesn't exist in DB2. If it already exists update is_active column to 0 of the existing row and insert the new row with is_active as 1.

I cannot use merge into as i cannot run 2 queries in when matched section.

How can i achieve this in batch.

If i were to run queries one by one i could have run them. But since there are streaming and there around 500msg per sec, i want to do this in batch

If we use statement we could have done

statement.addBatch(sql1)
statement.addBatch(sql2)

After doing above lets say 500 times we just execute batch
statement.excuteBatch()

But we are looking for something similar in prepared statement. When we tried to do it the same way as statement it failed

Comment: Side note: booleans almost always represent derived state as an answer to a question (often, as in this case, something time based).  **If** your query patterns support it, you _may_ get better results using a timestamp named `made_active_at` and just getting the most recent timestamp (this has performance issues if you're querying for large batches of active records at a time).

Answer (score 0):

You may combine 2 or more data change statements into a single statement, but it's a `SELECT` statement which you can't use in the `addBatch` method.
[Retrieval of result sets from an SQL data change statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0011133.html)
But you may use the `after update` trigger and the `insert` statement only in your `addBatch` method.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  ID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, KEY INT NOT NULL
, IS_ACTIVE INT NOT NULL
) IN USERSPACE1;

CREATE TRIGGER TEST_AIR 
AFTER INSERT ON TEST
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE TEST T SET IS_ACTIVE=0 WHERE T.KEY=N.KEY AND T.ID<>N.ID AND T.IS_ACTIVE<>0;

INSERT INTO TEST (KEY, IS_ACTIVE) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO TEST (KEY, IS_ACTIVE) VALUES (1, 1);
SELECT * FROM TEST;

|ID         |KEY        |IS_ACTIVE  |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|1          |1          |0          |
|2          |1          |1          |
```